# How to manage the versioning of Azure SQL Databases?

Tags: ansible, chef, azure

I am looking for a tool that will manage the versioning of Azure SQL Databases, and check for missing schema or migration scripts and apply those changes based on what is missing.

Any other solutions or tips would be great. I just want to make sure the database schema is flat across the board regardless, and apply changes based on version number.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

I assume from the `ansible` tag in your question that you need something that can run from a command line, so that rules out plugins to SSMS like [dbForge](https://sqlserver.pro/dbforge-sql-server-schema-comparison-and-sync-tool).

Try [Flyway](https://flywaydb.org) (has a free version) or [Red Gate](https://www.red-gate.com/products/sql-development/sql-compare/) (commercial).

Answer (score 0):

Did you try DbUp?
[DbUp homepage](https://dbup.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)  
This utility can apply patches to database and maintain its version.

It writes execution log to databases and is able to run scripts that were not applied.

I'm using that project over 3 years now and it does it job well.